# How to generate a VSCode theme preserving the names of custom colors?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, color-scheme

I want to change some colors of an installed theme and generate my theme from the theme's colors + my changes. E.g.:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Installed theme]": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "name": "My custom JSON Property Name",
                "scope": "support.type.property-name.json",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#424242"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Then I click **Developer: Generate Color Theme from Current Settings** and the name field is gone:

```json
{
    "scope": "support.type.property-name.json",
    "settings": {
        "foreground": "#424242"
    }
}
```

How can I generate a theme preserving these names?